# how to retrieve data between two dates in linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a datetime column in a table and I want to retrieve data month wise from this date time column. I want to populate a dropdown down list with month name only so that user can search data by month name. 
here is my linq code

```
        var filterdate = from dates in _db.entries
                         where date1 >= dates.PaidOn
                         where date2 <= dates.PaidOn
                         select dates;
        return View(filterdate);
```

and how to write the razor view code. please help. I am stuck. I would really appreciate your help. thanks in advance. Gitu

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
var filterdate = from dates in _db.entries
                 where date1 >= dates.PaidOn
                 && date2 <= dates.PaidOn
                 select dates.PaidOn.Month;
```

or

```
var filterdate = _db.entries.Where(i=> date1 >=i.PaidOn && date2 <= i.PaidOn )
                            .Select(i=>i.PaidOn.Month);
```

Comment: Yes, exaclty. What I understood he wants a dropdown with months.